# Java priority queue oder

Tags: java

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class minMaxHeap {

```
    static class PQsort implements Comparator<Integer> {

        public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
            return two - one;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ia = { 1, 10, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8 };
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        // use offer() method to add elements to the PriorityQueue pq1
        for (int x : ia) {
            pq1.offer(x);
        }
        for(int num : pq1){
            System.out.print(" " + num);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        PQsort pqs = new PQsort();
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10, pqs);
        // In this particular case, we can simply use Collections.reverseOrder()
        // instead of self-defined comparator
        for (int x : ia) {
            pq2.offer(x);
        }

        for(int num : pq2){
            System.out.print(" " + num);
        }



    }
```

}

I have code like this.
In java, I am using priority queue to store array of values.
When I try to print them one by one, I expect to see them been printed in order. Such as :1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
But why do I see "1 3 5 8 4 7 6 10 9"?

When I use reversedOrder by giving another comparator.
the result is also strange, which is
"10 9 7 8 4 5 1 4"
Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: What is your comparator?

Comment: @CPerkins sorry. Corrected my code. Copied wrong code piece before.

Comment: @BufBills please fix formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PriorityQueue` is not a replacement for a sorted collection! It just guarantees, that repeated dequeuing of elements (via `poll()`) removes them according to their priority, but internally, the elements need not be stored in completely sorted order.

JavaDoc of [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.
>   If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

JavaDoc of [`PriorityQueue#iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does
>   not return the elements in any particular order.

Reading docs usually doesn't hurt!